# Java 8 list to nested map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I hava a list of Class `A` like

```
class A {
 private Integer keyA;
 private Integer keyB;
 private String text;
}
```

I want to transfer `aList` to nested `Map` mapped by `keyA` and `keyB`

So I create below code.

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer,List<A>>> aMappedByKeyAAndKeyB = aList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getKeyA), result -> {
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<A>>> nestedMap = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, List<A>>>();
        result.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {nestedMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getKeyB)));});
        return nestedMap;}));
```

But I don't like this code.

I think If I use `flatMap`, I can better code than this.

But I don't know How use `flatMap` for this behavior.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Seems that you just need a cascaded `groupingBy`:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer,List<A>>> aMappedByKeyAAndKeyB = aList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getKeyA, 
                 Collectors.groupingBy(A::getKeyB)));
```