# How to create nested maps from flat sql select result set

Tags: java, guava, multimap

Having a SQL query similar to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGION, COUNTRY, CITY
```

Yielding this result set

```
REGION COUNTRY CITY
EUROPE FRANCE  PARIS
EUROPE FRANCE  LYON 
EUROPE FRANCE  NICE
EUROPE GERMANY BERLIN
EUROPE GERMANY DORTMUND 
EUROPE GERMANY HANNOVER
```

Is there a way to use google's ListMultimap so that I end up with a key -> value -> value structure?

E.g.

```
{EUROPE
    {GERMANY
       {BERLIN, DORTMUND, HANNOVER}, 
     FRANCE
       {PARIS, LYON, NICE}
     }
}
```

Or would another package be better suited for this?

EDIT:

Tried implementing @Prog_G's solution, but got out of memory with the below approach. I reckon that I have to transform outer to yet another data structure at the end. Would I create a Map out of this in some way?
PS. the real example is one more level deep, but wanted to keep it simpler for the sake of the question.

```
private static class GeoRowMapper implements RowCallbackHandler {

    ListMultimap<String, ListMultimap<String, ListMultimap<String, String>>> outer = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    ListMultimap<String, ListMultimap<String, String>> middle = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    ListMultimap<String, String> inner = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    @Override
    public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

        String region = rs.getString("region");
        String country = rs.getString("country");
        String city = rs.getString("city");
        String address = rs.getString("address");
        inner.put(city, address);
        middle.put(country, inner);
        outer.put(region, middle);
    }
    public ListMultimap<String, ListMultimap<String, ListMultimap<String, List<String>>>> get() {
        return Multimaps.asMap(outer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out Guava's [`Table`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html). Or just use a `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`.

Comment: Try this example:  
        ListMultimap<String, ListMultimap<String, List<String>>> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
            ListMultimap<String, List<String>> inner = ArrayListMultimap.create();
            inner.put("innerkey1", Arrays.asList("value1"));
            multimap.put("key1", inner);
            System.out.println(multimap.toString());

Comment: @gurioso, ideally I'd want to create a Map out of it at the end.

Comment: @Prog_G I tried implementing your solution, but am getting out of memory

Comment: Means, you mean this structure {EUROPE{GERMANY{BERLIN, DORTMUND, HANNOVER}, FRANCE{PARIS, LYON, NICE}}}?

Comment: That's correct, yes. In my real example, the result will be one more level deep, but this is essentially what I'm looking for, yes.
In a simpler example (made of Map<String, List<String>>), I used Multimaps.asMap(output)

Comment: Yes, I definitely will update this if I'll manage to get a working solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Bishonen_PL did you tried setting expectedvaluesperkey property of ArrayListMultimap. Can you tell on what condition you are getting out of memory error?

Comment: No, I think it is my wrong logic. 

  inner.put(city, address);
   middle.put(country, inner);
   outer.put(region, middle);

those three lines do not create an 'outer' which holds unique mappings as they are in the db table, but creates all possible combinations of those columns. This is because inner is saved from the previous loops, where the country is not necessarily the same as it is now. This then continues in outer, and creates a gigantic result instead of ~7k rows.

Comment: What properties do you want to query by? Do you want to get all contries per region? Get all cities? Lookup for an address? Compound keys or values could be a solution, depending on your use cases. Could you add address in your desired output structure?

Comment: I got the querying part done: it's a simple select distinct query, returning a table of ~400 rows x 4 columns. Now the whole task is to create a tree-structure, where the first object has the distinct values from col 1, its children are the associated values from col 2 and so on...

Comment: Turned out, `stream()` and `Collectors.groupingBy` does the trick with a minimum of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works with `stream()` and `Collectors.groupingBy` (credits go [here](https://apassionatechie.wordpress.com/2018/02/08/how-to-create-a-nested-map-using-collectors-groupingby/), see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33644790/1428369)). `Set` instead of `List` guarantees unique elements.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> grouped = 
    records.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.region,
                         Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.country,
                         Collectors.mapping(r -> r.city, Collectors.toSet()))));
```

given

```
class Record {
    String city;
    String region;
    String country;
}
```

Currently this will give you actually `HashMap`s and a `HashSet`. Their issue is a lack of guaranteed order when iterating their entries. Also you have no reordering or "insert at a index" operation available, if the structure should back a tree displayed in a user interface. E.g. [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) and [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) have a predictable iteration order. Still this approach may be ok as an intermediary step when creating the final tree data structure.

Depending on your taste the usage of `Map.computeIfAbsent` may be an option, which was introduced with [an eye on multimaps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8YX45ymAeE).

```
public Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> mumap(List<Record> records) {
    Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Record r : records) {
        result.computeIfAbsent(r.region, region -> new LinkedHashMap<>())
              .computeIfAbsent(r.country, country -> new TreeSet<>())
              .add(r.city);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your time. I already tried out your code yesterday but it didn't quite work. Now tried out the updated second approach, and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Bishonen_PL this was always a question I had in the back of my mind, but never approached it, due to lack of occasion. So, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Table`, as per Andy Turner's comment. In your case it would be something like:

```
ImmutableTable<Region, Country, ImmutableList<City>> immutableTable = RECORDS.stream()
        .collect(toImmutableTable(
                r -> r.getRegion(),
                r -> r.getCountry(),
                r -> ImmutableList.of(r.getCity()),
                (l, l2) -> ImmutableList.<City>builder().addAll(l).addAll(l2).build()
        ));
```

Or if you want mutable table as a result:

```
Table<Region, Country, List<City>> table = RECORDS.stream()
        .collect(toTable(
                r -> r.getRegion(),
                r -> r.getCountry(),
                r -> Lists.newArrayList(r.getCity()),
                (l, l2) -> {
                    l.addAll(l2);
                    return l;
                },
                HashBasedTable::create
        ));
```